# How do I create and increment a 2 or 3 digit hexadecimal number?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, adobe-indesign

How do I increment the highest hexidecimal number from an array of hexidecimal numbers? My knowledge of hexidecimal is somewhat spotty so any help would be appreciated. And to be perfectly honest I don't know if the numbers are hexadecimal or not because there is a "u" in front of them but they look that way if you remove the "u". The values are from an InDesign snippet document.

Example:

```
var anArray = ["uf9","ufc","u111","u112","u136","u137"]; // actual values

var getUniqueID = getNextHigherNumber(anArray);

function getNextHigherNumber(anArray) {
   // sort array
   // create variable and add one
   // return variable 
   return variable;
}
```

XML from the server (look at Self and Source):

```
<Hyperlink Self="ufc" Name="is a  multiline hyperlink that terminates here" Source="uf9" Visible="false" Highlight="None" Width="Thin" BorderStyle="Solid" Hidden="false" DestinationUniqueKey="1">
    <Properties>
        <BorderColor type="enumeration">Black</BorderColor>
        <Destination type="object">HyperlinkURLDestination/http%3a//test.com#1stMultilineLink/</Destination>
    </Properties>
</Hyperlink>
<Hyperlink Self="u112" Name="hyperlink inline" Source="u111" Visible="false" Highlight="None" Width="Thin" BorderStyle="Solid" Hidden="false" DestinationUniqueKey="2">
    <Properties>
        <BorderColor type="enumeration">Black</BorderColor>
        <Destination type="object">HyperlinkURLDestination/http%3a//test.com</Destination>
    </Properties>
</Hyperlink>
<Hyperlink Self="u137" Name="another multline hyperlink" Source="u136" Visible="false" Highlight="Outline" Width="Thick" BorderStyle="Solid" Hidden="false" DestinationUniqueKey="3">
    <Properties>
        <BorderColor type="enumeration">Purple</BorderColor>
        <Destination type="object">HyperlinkURLDestination/http%3a//google.com#multilinehyperlink</Destination>
    </Properties>
</Hyperlink>
```

More background:

I have an existing XML document that looks like it's using hexidecimal number system for it's IDs and I need to be able to create a unique ID for new nodes. The ID values look similar to HTML web colors like, "0xFF0000" (which is red) but the difference is that it is using 2 or 3 characters instead of 6, for example, "ufc" or "u112".

I receive an XML file from the server and it has nodes and each node has an ID with a unique value (see XML example above). If I have to create a new "item" I need to create a unique ID for it that isn't already used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you complicate things when thinking hexadecimal ;) You can just convert your hex values to decimal ones and then continue what you are doing, so you can do like this :

```
var anArray = ['u112', 'u136', 'uf9', 'u137', 'u111', 'ufc'];

var getUniqueID = getNextHigherNumber(anArray);

trace('u', getUniqueID);    // gives : u138

function getNextHigherNumber(anArray:Array):String {
    var max:int = 0;
    for(var i:int = 0; i<anArray.length; i++){
        // convert the hex value to an integer
        var num:int = int('0x' + String(anArray[i]).substr(1)); 
        // get the max value    
        if(num > max) max = num;
    }
    // return the hex value of (max value + 1)
    return (max + 1).toString(16);
}
```

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, hexadecimal is just a representation of a number.
The number itself remains the same.

Adding 2, means, take the value of this number, and add the value of 2.
Hexadecimal is just another way to write the number down.

Your effort of trying to figure out what these values are is highly appreciated, but why not check the documentation to know for sure?

You have an XML which you received with/from InDesign.
Just searching for that throws "IDML" at me, which seems to be the name Adobe gave to the format you are trying to parse.

Adobe provides a document describing this format: 
https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/indesign/cs55-docs/IDML/idml-specification.pdf

Section 10.1.1 is about the Self attribute:

> The Self attribute contains a unique identifier for the elements that
>   contain it. This identifier is used elsewhere in the IDML package to
>   refer to the element, as discussed in the “Object Reference
>   Format” section of this specification. Schema Example 2.
>   **Self attribute Self { xsd:string }**

As you can see, the value is a string, and not a number.

On page 31, you can find a description of how Adobe creates the values for Self including this statement:

> The only requirement of the value of the Self attribute is that it is
>   unique within the IDML package. If you are writing the IDML yourself,
>   you do not need to observe the above pattern— **you can change the value
>   of the Self attribute to anything you want as long as it is unique**
>   (within the IDML package) and as long as all references to the element
>   are also changed to match.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged both `JavaScript` and `ActionScript` (I don't know ActionScript), but the code in your question looks like JavaScript to me, and the other answer in here looks like it is in ActionScript; so, assuming you still want to do this (looks like user *null* is onto something), I will post the JavaScript equivalent:

```
var anArray = ["uf9","ufc","u111","u112","u136","u137"];

function getNextHigherNumber(theArray) {
    var maxNum = 0;
    theArray.forEach(function(num) {
        num = parseInt(num.substr(1), 16);
        if(num > maxNum) maxNum = num;
    });
    return 'u' + (maxNum + 1).toString(16);
}

// Run the function to see if it works
console.log(getNextHigherNumber(anArray));
```

What it does inside the *forEach* function/loop:

- Remove the "u" from each array element.
- Convert the string without the "u" to its *int* decimal equivalent.
- Store the number in **maxNum** if the current number is bigger than the previous stored **maxNum**.

And then it `returns` the biggest number plus one, converted back again to hex via `.toString(16)` (and prepending an 'u' to it).

Comment: Thanks. ActionScript 3 is like JavaScript but with the option to use strong types, classes and packages. If you know JavaScript you can start using AS3 the same day and you can pick up the new features of AS3 in a day or two.

Comment: That's good to know, yeah, I noticed the types in the ActionScript answer in the other reply. I just read a bit on it and ActionScript is actually now a "dialect" of ECMAScript (JavaScript's specification). It is an interesting fact, thanks. About your question, will you end up assigning an arbitrary ID to your XML nodes then? Just curious, really.

Comment: I used the function to translate all the IDs in the document to integers and they were all in sequence! So it was using hexadecimal in this case. Although the spec says you can use any value I'm going to follow their lead and so I'm getting the highest values from the IDs, adding one and then using that as the new ID.